# Openapi-generator to create jmeter script

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, openapi, openapi-generator

I'm using an openapi-generator-cli(5.4.0 v) jar to create a JMeter script. However, it is throwing errors for all the API's in swagger JSON.

[image]

I tried generating the script for pet store JSON. It's working.
Please let me know what could be the issue.

Comment: Can you post your OpenAPI JSON file and the openapi-generator command that you use?

Comment: you should post the text of the exception and the OpenAPI input

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible to use "openapi-generator-cli(5.4.0 v) jar to create a JMeter script", if you want to generate a JMeter test plan from the OpenAPI definition I would suggest doing this like:

1. Obtain [Taurus](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/taurus-new-star-test-automation-tools-constellation) tool
2. Use [swagger2yaml tool](https://gettaurus.org/docs/Swagger/#swagger2yaml-Convert-Swagger-specs-into-Taurus-YAML) to generate [Taurus YAML file](https://gettaurus.org/docs/YAMLTutorial/) from the API specification
3. Run Taurus as `bzt yaml-from-step-2.yml -gui` - it will open JMeter with the generated test plan
4. Save the test plan as [JMeter .jmx file](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/JMETER/JmxTestPlan)